# Why Does Alias Name does't show Server Name

Tags: oracle, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to connect Visual Studio 2017 (ASP.NET MVC5 App) with Oracle. 
I download `Oracle Development Tools`

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacdeploy-4242173.html

And I download ODP.NET Managed Driver, but after I try to connect to oracle database alias name doesn't show

[image]

I have no idea where I made mistake, and what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Please enter username and password for the connection or if it uses windows authentication, then click on the "Use Windows Authentication" checkbox and try again.

Comment: Noo, doesn't work. 
I get error Input string was not in a correct format